# Need clarity on below program,

Tags: c++

What will the below program print?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;    

static int x = 10;

void main1()    
{      
    cout << x << endl;    
    x = x + 1;    
}    

int main()   
{    
    main1();    
    main1();        
    cout << x << endl;    
}
```

As per my understanding, the above program we used static variable, so `x` retains the last initialized variable. So the output will be

```
10    
11    
12
```

but if we removed static, we should get

```
10    
10    
10
```

but I am getting the below output, even after removing static.

```
10    
11    
12
```

Please help me to understand.

Comment: Why do you think that removing `static` will make a difference?

Comment: The `x` variable is global.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if `int x` is not static, it is still a **global** variable, outside the scope of `main` and `main1`.

Thus whatever change you make to x from anywhere inside this file is going to change it permanently.

Comment: Just as a reminder : the only thing that changes when you remove `static` is the linker visibility of that variable.

Comment: thanks every one  for your time,understood after some more examples

Answer (score 0):

Since x is global visible to both main1 and main it will not make difference whether static is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

the static keyword has several meanings in C depending on where yoi use it. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd(v=vs.80).aspx